# TypeError: Network request failed for 204 (No Content) and 304 (Not Modified) call over HTTP2 (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Chrome)

Tags: http, http2, http-1.1, http-status-code-304, http-status-code-204

We have switched from `HTTP1.1` to `HTTP2` protocol and have noticed that some requests fail. When a server responds with `204` or `304` we get the following error:

> TypeError: Network request failed

Chrome additionally shows it with the following error on network tab: `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research we have found what the issue was. `HTTP2` protocol is stricter in it's syntax that `HTTP1.1` is. E.g. it does not allow body for `204` or `304` responses. It is logical that these responses should not contain body, but `HTTP1.1` did not require to fail these "strange" responses while `HTTP2` requires that a client does not accept such a response.

We have additionally found out that even though we did not have body or `content-length` header, we did have a `content-type` header which the browser does not accept either while the logic for `HTTP1.1` was just ignoring this header.

I did not find much information about this on the Internet at all. The closest I got was the [HTTP2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.6), and even it was a bit vague on details. It does not state directly that a `304` response that has a `content-type` header should be rejected, but I assume that's how browsers have implemented it in reality.

**TLDR:**

`204` and `304` responses cannot contain body, `content-length` or `content-type` header. Such responses will be treated as a network error by the browser (and probably other clients as well).

P.S. It is likely that there are similar restrictions for other response codes

P.P.S. Kudos to [Morten Cools](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576855/morten-cools) who has done original research on the topic